# Can I specify locking -schema- for a table or it depends on the transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

In Sybase, I can specify the locking schema for the table if it is, data rows, pages or table lock.
The below is an example in `SYBASE` how to create a table with specifying the lock table.

```
create  table dbo.EX_EMPLOYEE(
   TEXT   varchar(1000)  null
)
alter table EX_EMPLOYEE lock allpages
go
```

In SQL server there are such [lock tables(SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784172/what-are-row-page-and-table-locks-and-when-they-are-acquired) but can I specify the lock for the table?

My question: Can I specify the table type of locks ? or in SQL server it is different? Does it depend on the query that I run?

in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4931245-6c3d-4262-8fb1-20dd76622bae/what-is-default-locking-level-in-sql-server-2008-or-2008-r2?forum=sqldatabaseengine) it says :

> As Andreas pointed out there is no default locking level locks are
>   taken as per operation you are trying to perform in the database. Just
>   some examples. If it is delete/update for a particular row exclusive
>   lock will be taken on that row If it is select operation Shared lock
>   will be taken If it is altered table Schema Mod lock will be taken soon
>   and so forth As Jeremy pointed out If you are looking for Isolation
>   level it is read committed.

are they are right ? can I say that locking table in Sybase is different than SQL server?

Comment: If you create clustered index for your table and set index options ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS to OFF on it, what then happens? (I have not tried and thus no answer, just comment.)

Comment: @Arvo but my question is not about indexes and doesn't need to have index   to know the type of locks

Comment: @Moudiz - the Clustered Index is sometimes a confusing name - a clustered index on a table is the table, e.g. you could refer to it as a Clustered Table..

Comment: Moudiz already answered - clustered index IS in fact the table itself. What about 'doesnt need to have index' - sorry, this smells of bad design (actually locking of entire table is not good behavior either, but this was not your question :)). All tables should have primary key, which itself is an index; you can create it as clustered (by default it is) and then you have all requirements fulfilled.

Comment: @Arvo well as this [so question explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean) clustered index is something else , thats why i was confused. as for the set index option is for the all the index in the database or specified  in the table ?

Comment: Index option is for single index only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locking mechanisms are not the same, but you do have some control in SQL Server for locking - you can specify `with rowlock`, `with paglock` or `with (tablockx)` for example on a query to take an exclusive table lock.

As with all such locks when you take control - you have to take responsibility for the blocking you can cause - so use carefully.

Docs with full descriptions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Comment: yes in a query I can specify the type of lock [explained here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server) but in the documents it doesn't mention the table if it has lock. so my question is about the table locks not query , so as i understand from you the table has no locks right ?.

Comment: The table will only be locked if there is an operation, whether DDL or DML requiring the lock.

Comment: if i am updating table T1 , then a table lock will happen on it right ? i cannot select or update on it on different session correct ? if i added hint on it then it can be row lock right ?

Comment: If you use a holdlock, tablockx in a transaction, it will take out an exclusive table lock for your update and hold it for the duration of the transaction. That may / may not prevent others selecting though, depending on the transaction isolation level being used. It will prevent updates.