# Difference between table and row locks

Tags: mysql, table-locking, rowlocking

I'm studying about MySQL and how it works, and something confuses me and I don't find any clear explanation on the web about this.

What exactly is the difference between row and table locks? One locks the row and the other locks the table. Correct?

So, in which sort of situations would you use a table lock and row lock? Is it something the programmer or database manager can program in or it is the enigne that does it for you?

If there is any other information you think is good to know, feel free to add that to your answer.
I'm sorry for this possible noobish question, but I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is SQL server, it applies well to mySQL as well: [What are row, page and table locks? And when they are acquired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784172/what-are-row-page-and-table-locks-and-when-they-are-acquired).

[MySQL docs shows this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-locking.html#internal-locking-choices):

Generally, table locks are superior to row-level locks in the following cases:

- Most statements for the table are reads.
- Statements for the table are a mix of reads and writes, where writes are updates or deletes for a single row that can be fetched with one key read:
- SELECT combined with concurrent INSERT statements, and very few UPDATE or DELETE statements.
- Many scans or GROUP BY operations on the entire table without any writers.

Now when to use:  The infamous "It depends" applies here:
Ask yourself what is the use case for this transaction?

Typically row level locking will be used when high granular control is needed.  In my opinion this should be used as the default.  Say a orders or orders detail table where the order could be updated or deleted.  Locking the whole table on a high transaction volume table makes no sense.  I want users of individual orders to be able to update each order and not lock someone else out when I know the scope of their change is a limited to a specific order.

Now if I needed to restore the orders and details table from backup for some reason; or make many updates to many records based on an external source; I may lock the whole table to ensure all the updates complete successfully and I can verify the load before I let anyone back in.  I don't want any changes while I'm making the needed updates.   But we have to consider if locking the whole table will negatively impact user experience; or if we have no other options available.  Locking at the table level will prevent other users from changing any value.  IS this really what we want?